# Passing argument in instance variable in Ruby gets error

Tags: ruby

```
class Account
 attr_reader :name
 attr_reader :balance
 def initialize(name, balance=100)
   @name = name
   @balance = balance
 end

 public
 def display_balance(pin_number)
  if pin_number == pin
   puts "Balance: $#{@balance}."
  else
   puts pin_error
  end
 end

 def withdraw(pin_number,amount)
   if pin_number == @pin
     @balance -= amount
     puts "Withdrew #{amount}."
   else
     puts pin_error
   end
 end
 def deposit(pin_number,amount)
   if pin_number ==@pin
     @balance+=amount
     puts"Deposited"
  else
     puts pin_error
  end
 end

 private
 def pin
   @pin = 1
 end
 def pin_error
   return "Access denied: incorrect PIN."
 end 
 end

checking_account=Account.new("bob",200)
checking_account.deposit(1,20)
```

When i try deposit i get an error on pin, but when i remove the @ in the pin checks and treat it as a normal variable it works. In codeacademy it shows that the correct way to check the pin is with

```
  if pin_number==@pin
```

yet it doesn't work, even though it should, why is that?

Comment: Don't change the code like that. It's now a completely different piece of code, with a completely different error.

Comment: I took the liberty of rolling back your code changes, because they were disagreeing with the text.

Comment: No the error remained the same, when i pass the pin i get the pin error, that's what i am saying

Comment: No, you get a completely different pin error. ("can't call private method `pin`")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pin_number==@pin` will return `false`, because you never set `@pin` - so it will still be `nil`.

Instead of using a private method, you could do something like this:

```
def initialize(name, pin, balance=100)
  @name = name
  @pin = pin
  @balance = balance
end

# ...

checking_account=Account.new("bob", 1, 200)
checking_account.deposit(1, 20)
```

Comment: It is initializes, you have to scroll down a bit at the private pin method

Comment: No. Defining a method does not initialize the variable. That is precisely the mistake you made, which I have corrected.

Comment: If you **call** the method, in the initializer or otherwise, then the variable will be initialized. But you did not call the method anywhere.

Comment: By initializing the pin it works, but no such thing was done from the site, so there is a mistake in their code, i submitted a report about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> yet it doesn't work, even though it should, why is that?

Because your `@pin` is never initialized. Something must be different between your code and what they have at codecademy (they likely initialize `@pin` in the initializer, which you do not).

> but when i remove the @ in the pin checks and treat it as a normal variable

**Wrong.**. This is not a variable. When you make it `pin` instead of `@pin`, it starts pointing to that private method of yours. Which returns a pin number. That's why it works.

---

Note that your code will work as-is, if you simply `display_balance` before making a deposit. This is called "call order dependency" and it's bad.

Comment: It is initializes, you have to scroll down a bit at the private pin method

Comment: @ChristopherBovo: IF you call that method, sure. But you don't call it (in  your example)

Comment: I replaced the code with the code given by the codeacademy one, and i call the method and it still doesn't work, also you can't call the method since it's private, if anyone can find the error please point me to it

Comment: @ChristopherBovo: Tom posted working code, compare it with yours and find the difference.  Also see the note at the end of my answer.